# Is there a way to easily transfer files from a Mac to a PC and vice versa via router?

Tags: windows, windows-10, macos, file-transfer, macos-bigsur

My household has an iMac (Big Sur 11.1) and a Windows laptop (Windows 10). I regularly need to transfer big files from one machine to the other. These files are often pretty big (e.g., more than 10 GB).

The standard way of moving the files is via a USB stick or an external HDD. Alternatively, I can upload these files to the cloud (e.g., Dropbox) using one machine and download them from the other.

However, both ways are cumbersome and/or slow. Considering that the two machines share the same network I should be able to able to transfer files from one another easily, e.g., by droping the files into a folder that's accessible to both.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In macOS, you can share a folder over the local network and restrict remote access to the shared folder. From the Windows end, you open Explorer (or any other SMB browser) and enter the Mac's IP-address to access the folder. Here you can give both read and write access to the Windows machine so it can both retrieve as well as send files.

You enable this by open System Settings -> Sharing -> Filesharing. Enable file sharing and add the folder that contains your file you want to share (or where you want the file to appear). To allow Windows users to connect to your Mac, open options and enable each user account.

Comment: There's a full guide from the Mac side here - https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchlp1657/mac

Answer (score 1):

A Mac can use a [samba share](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/how-do-i-connect-a-mac-os-x-machine-to-a-samba-share/), as can [Windows](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-connect-to-linux-samba-shares-from-windows-10/). Using the full [UNC path](https://www.lifewire.com/unc-universal-naming-convention-818230) to the shared folder I find more reliable than trying to discover it in Network.

That said, I've find smb file transfer abysmally slow. On a router theoretically capable of 450 Mbps transfer [*note, speed given in bits per second*], and actually delivering 300-350 Mbps throughput from my ISP, PC-router-PC speed seems to max out around 10 or 20 Mbps. Sorry, I have no explanation for that speed reduction by more than an order of magnitude on my PC's, and others have mentioned faster throughput.

With that in mind, sneaker-net doesn't seem so bad. By router, a 10 GB file transfer might take 15 minutes. If the USB drive is fast, it could beat the "speed of light".

Another issue I've had with smb in older versions of Windows is that large transfers may terminate prematurely. For me, "pulling" a file from the receiving end has been more reliable than "pushing" from the sender, though, again, others have found the opposite true, so experiment with both.

Comment: Just tested a single movie file, 'push' Mac>PC samba over Ethernet (HD to HD) - 4GB in 1 minute, so slightly better than 500mpbs. Nowhere near theoretical limit but quite acceptable. Pulling the same file crashed the PC, which after reboot now can't see the Mac share… but the Mac can see the PC & correctly connect. It's far from perfect ;) I always find it 'safer' to initiate the connection from the Mac.

Comment: Doing this now for over an hour has reminded me why I hate file sharing on Windows. It is utterly intransigent. It now will not connect to the Mac, even typing the smb:\\ into iti… though the Mac is currently sharing & copying files quite happily when the connection is initiated the other way. Windows, even on current Win10, is still perfectly at ease believing two conflicting pieces of information simultaneously. I really don't understand how it has kept its presence on the world stage.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I've had similar issues for Linux <-> Windows, while Linux <-> Linux smb is rock steady. *Now if I could figure out how to make files sent from Windows fully available to Linux users without needing to use chmod...*